# How to redirect URL from old WebForms site to subdomain on new MVC5 site using MVC routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are in the middle of migrating and updating our current website from WebForms to MVC5. One part of the current site will be decoupled and remain running on WebForms as a standalone site for the time being and will become accessible on its own subdomain in the new situation.

In the current situation we have a bunch of URL's looking like this:

`www.site.com/foo/[..]/bar.aspx`

In the new situation we would like to redirect these URL's to something like this:

`www2.site.com/foo/[..]/bar.aspx`

I was thinking of using a `Route` in MVC5 that captures all incoming requests starting with `foo` and routing it to a `Redirect` controller. Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "RedirectFooBar", url: "foo(/.*)", defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "FooBar" });

public ActionResult FooBar()
{
    return RedirectPermanent(Request.RawUrl.Replace("//www.", "//www2."));
}
```

Unfortunately, my route is not working like this, because of the regular expression in the url. I would like to know if it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with MVC routing and if it is possible, what changes should I make to get this to work?

Or maybe there are better ways to achieve this sort of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you're using the wrong syntax. You should define your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "RedirectFooBar", url: "foo/{*path}", defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "FooBar" });
```

The `{*path}` will capture everything from this point to the end of the url. You can then use it as a parameter in your action:

```
public ActionResult FooBar(string path)
{
    return RedirectPermanent("http://www2.site.com/foo/" + path);
}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a bunch, didn't know about the `{*path}` parameter :)